# Zazzle.com Image Zoom effect using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins

Is there a jQuery plugin that mimics the Zazzle.com photo zoom effect (you can view the effect here: http://www.zazzle.com/awards+tshirts).  The closest I've found is the jQZoom plugin which opens the larger image in a separate container, instead of overlaying within the same container.

I figured I'd ask, before I started building away on this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they are using this javascript framework: http://www.uize.com/